# How to downgrade Radeon R9 380 with new driver?

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon

The new Radeon driver drives me nuts. With the old drivers it was very easy to downgrade the memory and gpu speed to keep the card cool.

With the new driver I can not find the position where the options is. The result is, that the card gets up to 80°C and the fan gets extremely annoying.

How to to downgrade the card with the new drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get the driver version of your choice. You can find old drivers from AMDs site [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous?os=Windows%207%20-%2064) or from a third party source [here](http://filehippo.com/download_ati_catalyst_vista_64/16004/).

Once you have this, uninstall your current drivers using [these instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Uninstall.aspx):

***Note - After this you will be on a basic graphics driver. As such your resolution may change, and any monitor/video settings will be lost***

1. Start by opening the Control Panel. 
   For Windows® 10/8.1, right-click on the Windows button and select Control Panel from the Context Menu - ***For Windows® 7, click on the `Windows button` and select `Control Panel` from the Start Menu***
2. In the `Control Panel` select `Programs and Features`
3. Select `AMD Install Manager` and then click `Uninstall/Change`
4. Check all items, and then click the `Uninstall` button.

   Note: If you had others versions of AMD drivers installed previously, you should get an additional prompt providing the options to remove `All Versions` or `Current Version`.

   Select All Versions to remove all AMD drivers and application components (recommended).
5. The uninstall process will begin removing drivers and software components.
6. Select Restart Now to complete the uninstallation process.

Following this, install the older driver you downloaded previously.